# Password Functionality Not Permitting Access

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords

I am using CodeIgniter - the latest version as of 12/4/2014.

I am trying to write a password functionality into my website for a company login portal. The portal isn't written at all yet, just the functionality. It displays and doesn't give me any errors except the ones for "invalid password." I have no idea where the problem is. So I am including all APPLICABLE resources

UPDATE! I found where the problem is, now I just need to know how to fix it the RIGHT way. On my Model I have encrypted passwords using MD5. I took that off after running the profiler and seeing the encrypted password being generated and sent either from the database or the application, I am not sure. Anyways after that the password let me through, and denies access when needed. How would I keep the encryption?

----MODEL----
Company_user

```
    <?php

class Company_user extends CI_Model {
    function login($username, $password){
        $this->db->select('company_user_id, username, password');
        $this->db->from('company_user');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
```

----CONTROLLERS----

Login

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $title = 'ImpactU Online';
        $subtitle = 'Company Login Portal';
        $subhead = 'Login Below';
        $this->load->view('template/header', array(
            'title' => $title,
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
            'subhead' => $subhead,
        ));
        $attributes = array(
            'class' => 'pure-form pure-form-stacked alert alert-info',
        );
        $this->load->view('login_view', array(
            'attributes' => $attributes,
        ));
        $this->load->view('submit');
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

Verfiylogin

```
       <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Verifylogin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('company_user', '', TRUE);
    }

    function index() {
        //This method will have the credentials validation
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
            $title = 'ImpactU Online';
            $subtitle = 'Company Login';
            $subhead = 'Login Below.';
            $attributes = array(
                'class' => 'pure-form pure-form-stacked alert alert-info',
            );
            $this->load->view('template/header', array(
                'title' => $title,
                'subtitle' => $subtitle,
                'subhead' => $subhead,
            ));
            $this->load->view('login_view', array(
                'attributes' => $attributes,
            ));
            $this->load->view('submit');
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
        } else {
            //Go to private area
            redirect('company_home', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function check_database($password) {
        //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        //query the database
        $result = $this->company_user->login($username, $password);

        if ($result) {
            $sess_array = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $sess_array = array(
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'username' => $row->username
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            }
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Company_home

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
class Company_home extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $title = 'ImpactU Online';
     $subtitle = 'Welcome To the Company Portal';
     $subhead = 'Please Select an Option';
     $this->load->view('template/header', array(
        'title' => $title,
        'subtitle' => $subtitle,
        'subhead' => $subhead,
     ));
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $this->load->view('company_home_view', $data);
     $this->load->view('template/footer');
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
 }

 function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('company_home', 'refresh');
 }

}
```

----VIEWS----

template/header

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title><?php echo html_escape($title); ?></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/favicon.ico"); ?>" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/favicon.ico"); ?>" type="image/x-icon">
        <link 
            href="<?php
            echo base_url('assets/css/impactU.css');
            ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            />
        <link 
            href="<?php
            echo base_url('assets/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
            ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            />
        <link 
            href="<?php
            echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
            ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/grids-responsive-min.css">
        <link 
            href="<?php
            echo base_url('assets/css/side-menu.css');
            ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            />
        <script>
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                a = s.createElement(o),
                        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                a.async = 1;
                a.src = g;
                m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-57039794-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="layout">
            <!-- Menu toggle -->
            <a href="#menu" id="menuLink" class="menu-link">
                <!-- Hamburger icon -->
                <span></span>
            </a>

            <div id="menu">
                <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open">
                    <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">ImpactU</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/blog'); ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
                                Blog
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/store'); ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                                Store
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/contact'); ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                Contact
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/about'); ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                                About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item-divided"><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/login'); ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                Company Login
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item-divided"><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/paypal'); ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>
                                Paypal Demo
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="main">
                <div class="header">
                    <h1><?php echo html_escape($title); ?></h1>
                    <h2><?php echo html_escape($subtitle); ?></h2>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <h2 class="content-subhead"><?php echo html_escape($subhead); ?></h2>
```

template/footer

```
    <hr/>
<div class="footer">
    <p><i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> 2014 Tyler Lazenby</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="<?php $this->load->helper('url');
echo base_url('assets/js/ui.js'); ?>">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

login_view

```
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('c=verifylogin', $attributes); ?>
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <label for = "password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required/>
    </div>
</div>
```

submit

```
    <legend>Click submit when done</legend>
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
</div>
```

company_home_view

```
    <h2 class="content-subhead">Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
   <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
```

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I already found one error that you might catch, but it isn't the solution; the "id" should be "computer_user_id" on line 55 of the Verifylogin controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple, just take the encryption out of the model.